# C++ Builder 2010. Can't load package. Unable to find module

Tags: package, rad-studio, bpl

I just installed Builder C++ 2010. I've always used it in Windows 7, but I've upgraded to Windows 10 and now I have a problem with BPL: I've opened a project with some components created by me, which I usually worked with in Windows 7, and when I right-click and click "Install" it compiles and link correctly but then a dialog box appears saying "Can't load package C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0\BPL\XXX.bpl. Can't find the specified module"

I looked in that folder and the bpl is there.I have made sure my user has been assigned full control over both the folder and the bpl. The folder is in the system path.

I have tried to do this directly from the Component / Install packages / add menu bar, but the same thing happens, although it sometimes says "integer overflow".

I'm afraid it has to do with the restrictions of Windows 10. Can someone give me a hand? Thanks in advance!

Jose.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Comment: Nevertheless, I'm able to add a different set of components, also made by myself. I see no difference between them

Comment: Well, it seems that the problem rises when I use functions contained in ftgl.lib and / or freetype-bcc.lib. I don't know exactly why this is happening.